# SCHTASKS Task Failure - Remote server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to run SCHTASKS from a 2012R2 server that starts a task on a remote server (server 2019).

1. Running C:\Windows\system32>schtasks.exe /run /s [remote servername(server 2019)] /TN "Folder\Task" from a cmd prompt on server 2012R2 returns ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified.
2. No issues running the task if I change the remote server to a server running 2008R2.  SCHTASKS version on 2008R2 = 6.1.7601.17514, SCHTASKS version on 2012R2 = 6.3.9600.18001, SCHTASKS version on 2019 = 10.0.17763.1.

Could this be a compatibility issue with SCHTASKS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after opening RPC on NSX Micro Segmentation.